# Launching a specific chrome profile in C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, processstartinfo

I have 3 chrome profiles and I'm using C# WinForms 2022 to load each profile in a single panel in a WinForm.
I know how to launch, for example, the private profile in a single panel, something like this

```
var url = "https://google.com";
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("chrome.exe");
process.StartInfo.Arguments = url + " --incognito";
```

The above code works well. But now I'm trying to add two panels to the same form and load chrome profiles 2 and 3 into panels 2 and 3 respectively.
I'm using the following code for profile 3 but it doesn't do any good to me

```
var url = "https://google.com";
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("chrome.exe");
process.StartInfo.Arguments = url + @"--profile-directory =""Profile 3""";
```

or

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = url + "--profile-directory=\"Profile3\"";
```

I'm unable to load a specific profile in any panel except the private profile and the default one.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code is working i think you missed the space near to --profile.

```
var url = "https://google.com";
            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("chrome.exe");
            //process.StartInfo.Arguments = url + " --incognito";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = url + @" --profile-directory=""Profile 2""";
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks a lot. This space drove me crazy!!

Comment: @Stephan Bauer , Can please take a quick look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70186553/how-to-load-two-chrome-profiles-into-two-panels-in-c-sharp-winform), it is related to this question as well. Thanks